# How to mount truecrypt volume in linux from command line without having the file manager opened?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, truecrypt

How do I mount a truecrypt volume in ubuntu from the CLI without a nautilus window being opened?

**O/S:** Ubuntu 12.10

**TrueCrypt:** 7.1a

**Command (that opens nautilus):**

> echo "MySuperSecretPassword" | $truecrypt --text /path/to/volume --mount /path/to/mount_point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `truecrypt` is built to invoke Nautilus, so the reason Nautilus pops up is that it "sees" a new filesystem appearing.

Therefore, I'd try disabling *automount-open* option in Nautilus, as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191527/disable-auto-opening-nautilus-window-after-auto-mount) (requires `dconf-editor`).

Comment: Agreed.Thank you for thinking outside of the box.

Comment: @ZS6JCE if you want to disable opening the file manager only for a single mount, you can do it with a hack like me :) 1) `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false` 2) `# truecrypt command` 3) `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open true`

Answer (score 1):

```
su -c "truecrypt --non-interactive  truecrypt-file cryptshare -p PASSWORD"
```

(Found on commandlinefu.com.)

Comment: I do not feel comfortable using the -p flag, as this will show the clear text password when "ps aux | grep truecrypt" is issued.

Is there a way to safely automate the mounting of a volume without the file manager being launched?